# Regarding definition tag

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, tags

I believe that it will be very useful to introduce `definition` tag in the main site.

A related tag `terminology` exists in that site but definition tag allows us to properly and precisely define the terms. Is it okay to introduce that tag as a separate tag?

Comment: Definition is a synonym of terminology.

Answer (score 2):

There's already [etymology](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etymology) tag which serves the same purpose.